# Quote (') is detected as Tilde (~) in Web Browsers (and vice versa)

Tags: windows, keyboard, keyboard-layout

I've run into an issue with web browser event handlers where the tilde (~) and quote (') characters are getting picked up the wrong way round. When I enter a quote a text field will have a quote entered into it, but the event handler will trigger as if a tilde was pressed.

I think this gif best shows what I'm trying to say:

[image]

As you can see, when the tilde/hash key is pressed, the browser detects a quote press, and when the quote key is pressed, the browser detects a tilde press.

Is there any way to fix this so that the correct keypress event is triggered?

---

Keyboard: Corsair K95 RGB Platinum (BrE layout)

OS: Windows 10 Home

Keyboard settings: English (United Kingdom)

Browser: Google Chrome Version 76.0.3809.100 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: It's the operating system reporting the UK-keyboard's single-quote keycode (192) as the US-keyboard's tilde keycode (192). Not sure how this can be fixed though since it is an OS not browser issue...

Comment: @SamuelLiew If that's the case is the only option to properly detect keypresses in browser event handlers to compare the `key` field to the character it's meant to represent?

Comment: The top keyboard is ANSI layout [US] the bottom one is ISO [UK] - they have keys in different places. Try setting your own keyboard layout to 'English International' or US instead of UK.

Comment: @Tetsujin The top keyboard is just a basic online keyboard tester (the first hit for typing "keyboard tester" into Google), would setting my keyboard layout to US-Int not result in me getting different keys to those laid out on my physical keyboard? - I'm not at home PC atm so can add any clarifications when home

Comment: The tester is misinterpreting the location of the key - it does the same for me as I'm also on an ISO keyboard. The characters typed in the test space are the correct ones according to what I press, just the ANSI tester misinterprets the locations… because they are in different places on ISO & ANSI. ANSI has no key left of z, tilde is where § is on an ISO keyboard, @ and " are usually swapped too. If you swap your keyboard to ANSI it will read the positions differently, so both will be 'wrong' but will agree to a greater degree.

Comment: @Tetsujin And I assume there's no way to have the correct key marked on the tester while also having the correct keys typed based on my keyboards actual layout (as in no way for me to press tilde on my UK keyboard, have a tilde get typed on the screen and have tilde marked on the tester)

Comment: Not unless you can find an ISO tester, or more specifically a British English one [because there are dozens of versions of ISO but only one ANSI (give or take)]. I couldn't find one, all ANSI.

Comment: @Tetsujin Alright thanks, if you want to compile that info in an answer I'll accept it, will just work around the problem, I'd rather leave my keyboard layout as it is :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't an easy one to "fix" because the fault is in the online interpreter.

There are two basic keyboard layouts, ANSI, which is used almost exclusively in the US, & ISO, used by pretty much everyone else.

Essentially, the keyboards are physically different in layout, even on otherwise 'identical' language mappings, US vs UK English, for example; ANSI has no key left of z & so it puts backtick ` and tilde ~  above caps lock, left of 1, where an ISO [UK] keyboard would have backtick ` and the logical negation sign ¬ [Windows]  or § and ± [Mac].  Pipe | and backslash \ are moved to the right of the brackets keys, where there is no corresponding key on ISO, but is instead one row lower. This key maps on Mac, but not on Win.
@ and " are typically swapped too [Win but not Mac].

Wikipedia has the various layouts applicable to just [QWERTY keyboards here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QWERTY) including Mac/Win differences.

This is before we get to the added complexity of non-English keyboards where even QWERTY changes, to AZERTY or QWERTZ etc.

[Wikipedia - Keyboard Layouts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyboard_layout) goes some way towards explaining the myriad differences in different language layouts.

Any online keyboard interpreter would need to know all of these in order to accurately test every possible key combination.

Some difference below - [images from Wikipedia, QWERTY page.]

US ANSI

[image]

UK ISO - Windows

[image]

UK ISO - Mac

[image]